# What is the difference between image labelling and object detection in google ml kit?

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter google ml kit in my app but it shows that object detection isn't available on the ios devices but the image labelling does, so I want to know the difference between them, and using this package is totally free right with unlimited requests ?

To know the difference between image labelling and object detection